# Incorrect result for %p when implementation printf

Tags: c, printf

I'm working on my own `printf` code and I got 2 problems that I hoped you might be able to help me with.

The first one is with the `%p` option :

This option gives me the pointer address of a `void*` in hex form.
So what I'm doing is this :

```
void    printp(void *thing)
{
    dectohex((long)&thing, 1);
}
```

where `dectohex` is just a function converting a `decimal` to `hex`.
The result will always be correct, except for the last 3 characters. Always. For example :

```
me : 0x5903d8b8 , printf : 0x5903da28.
```

And these characters don't change very often, whereas the other part changes at each call like its supposed to.

The other problem I have is with the `%O` option. I can't manage to convert a signed int to an `unsigned int`. `printf` prints huge numbers for `negative int's`, and no casts seems to work since I wouldn't have the place to store it anyways.

EDIT: 
Thanks sooo much for the answers, so apparently for the first problem i was just a little stupid. For the second question i'm gonna try the different solutions you gave me and update you if i manage to do it.

Again thanks so much for your time and patience, and sorry for the delay in my response, i checked the email alert for any answer but it doesn't work apparently.

REEDIT: After reading your answers to my second question more carefully, i think some of you think i asked about %o or %0. I was really talking about %O as in %lo i think. In the man it tells me "%O : The long int argument is converted to unsigned octal". My problem is before converting the long int to octal, i need to convert it to something unsigned.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `&thing`? That will give you the address *of the pointer*, i.e. you will get a pointer to the pointer, and not the actual address stored in the pointer.

Comment: Some libraries implement `%O` as a synomym for `%lo`. Is that what you meant or did you mean `%o`?

Comment: For your `%o` (lower case) problem: You needn't (and shouldn't) convert a signed `int`, fetch the corresponding arg as `unsigned int` (or `unsigned long` etc depending on length modifiers) and output it.

Comment: Post the declaration of `dectohex()`.

Comment: Post functional definition of `%O`.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.  That said, I predict `dectohex` is converting to float and then back to an integral type, losing a little bit of precision in the low bits.  But we wouldn't have to make crazy guesses like this if we could see the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `uintptr_t/intmax_t` is defined (it is optional), convert the pointer to that integer type and then print.

Otherwise, if `sizeof(uintmax_t) >= sizeof (void *)` , convert to `uintmax_t`.  `uintmax_t` is a required type, but may not be sufficiently large.

```
void printp(void *thing) {
  uintptr_t j = (uintptr_t) thing;
  char lst[(sizeof j * CHAR_BIT + 3)/ 4 + 1]; // Size needed to print in base 16
  char *p = &lst[sizeof lst] - 1;
  *p = '\0';
  do {
    p--;
    *p = "0123456789ABCDEF"[j%16];
    j /= 16;
  } while (p > lst);
  fputs(p, stdout);
}
```

---

The `%O` problem is likely a sign extension issue. (@mafso)  Insure valuables used are unsigned, like `unsigned` and `unsigned long`.  Without seeing the code difficult to know for sure.

Comment: should `*p == ` be `*p = `?

Answer (score 2):

About the first issue you're having, just to make sure, you want to print the address of thing (note that thing itself is a pointer) or the address of the `origin` of thing (the pointer to the pointer thing)?

You're currently printing the pointer to the pointer.

Change

```
dectohex((long)&thing, 1);
```

to

```
dectohex((long)thing, 1);
```

if that is the case.

About the `%O` problem, can you give a code example?

Comment: Casting to `long` will do no good in 64-bit Windows using the Visual Studio C compiler, as there `long` is still only 32 bits. Instead if anything should be used it should be `intptr_t`.

Comment: Not really sure this guy is running Windows, how did you deduct that?

Comment: It doesn't matter, `long` on Windows was just an example. The problem is that you don't know what size `long` is, as it depends on the compiler used. Instead use a type that is guaranteed to be big enough to fit an integer or a pointer (like `intptr_t`).

Comment: Guys, thanks for the input. However, the person asking this question is using 32bit pointers, so even signed long should work, and I referred to that. To be perfectly correct, unsigned long is a (in most cases correct) assumption on unpredictable pointer size, so the best cast would have to be platform dependent (e.g uintptr_t on unices).

Comment: You should access the pointer value as a `unsigned char[sizeof(void*)]` array and print out each character in hexadecimal.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: ... **if** such a type exists.

Comment: @NisseEngström You mean `intptr_t`? It's a type defined in the standard, so it should exist.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) says that `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` are optional. I don't have the actual standard and haven't checked any TC's or anything.

Comment: Yes, they are optional, for a simple reason: not all archs have pointers that are simply expressible as integers. But in that case the approach doesn't work anyhow, casting to any integer type would give garbage, so for this question here we can safelty assume that they exist.

Answer (score 1):

You need "unsigned long long" for your cast.

Pointers are unsigned, but long is signed.

The number of bits in any data type is implementation-dependent; however these days it is common for long and unsigned long to be 32 bits.

edit: to be more clear, you can't count on anything about the number of bits in C, C++ or Objective-C, it's always implementation-dependent.  For example it was at one time common to have nine bit bytes and thirty-six bit words.  That's why the Internet Protocols always specify "octets" - groups of eight bites - rather then "bytes".

That's one advantage of Java, in that the number of bits in each data type is strictly definited.

Comment: `unsigned long long` is not good either. Nothing guarantees that pointers have sizes not larger than `unsigned long long`. `intprt_t` and `uintprt_t` is the correct solution

Answer (score 0):

About your second question regarding zero-padding and negative integers, which seems entirely separate from the first question about hex output. You can handle negative numbers like this (although in 32-bit it does not work with the value -2147483648 which is 0x80000000).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXDIGITS   21

int printint(int value, int zeropad, int width)
{
    int i, z, len = 0;
    char strg [MAXDIGITS+1];
    strg [MAXDIGITS] = 0;

    if (value < 0) {
        value = - value;
        putchar ('-');
        len = 1;
    }

    for (i=MAXDIGITS-1; i>=0; i--) {
        strg [i] = '0' + value % 10;
        if ((value /= 10) == 0)
            break;
    }

    if (zeropad)
        for (z=MAXDIGITS-i; z<width; z++) {
            putchar ('0');
            len++;
        }

    for (; i<MAXDIGITS; i++) {
        putchar (strg [i]);
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int num = 0, len;
    if (argc > 1) {
        sscanf (argv[1], "%d", &num);
        // try the equivalent of printf("%4d, num);
        len = printint (num, 0, 4);
        printf ("   length %d\n", len);
        // try the equivalent of printf("%04d, num);
        len = printint (num, 1, 4);
        printf ("   length %d\n", len);
    }
    return 0;
}
```